# iOS 7 annotation pin image changed when pin is dragged

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mapkit, ios7

I have an annotation pin that I use to display the current search location which can be dragged. This annotation is just a normal MKPointAnnotation which I then change the image in the viewForAnnotation method. This is fine until I begin to drag the annotation, after which the annotation changes to the default red pin and loses the custom image I had set.

I create and add the annotation like this:

```
MKPointAnnotation *userAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[userAnnotation setCoordinate:userCoordinate];
[userAnnotation setTitle:@"My Location"];
[userAnnotation setSubtitle:@"Drag to move - Press to reset"];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:userAnnotation];
```

Then I set the annotationView like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
....
[annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"locationpin"]];
[annotationView setDraggable:YES];
[annotationView.layer setZPosition:999];
return annotationView;
```

And I implement the method didChangeDragState: fromState: like so:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {

    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        self.mockLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:droppedAt.latitude longitude:droppedAt.longitude];

        NSLog(@"%@ mock location set to %f %f", [self class], droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);

        [self plotStations];
    }
}
```

I don't recall this issue on iOS 6 but it is for sure existing on iOS 7.

So, how can I make it retain its image before, during, and after dragging?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem also.
I manage to solve this by changing from "MKPinAnnotationView" to "MKAnnotationView" on viewForAnnotation.

Something like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pin = (MKAnnotationView *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"my_pin"];
    if (pin == nil) {
        pin = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier:@"my_pin"];

    } else {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }

    pin.draggable = YES;
    pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_map_pin"];
    pin.selected = YES;

    return pin;
}
```

The difference is that the drag and drop wont show the animation of pin drop.

Hope it helps someone.